# Colored text in the console Python 3.6.4

Tags: python, colors, console, colorama

Is there any way to print in the console with colored text?

```
>>> from colorama import Fore 
>>> print(Fore.BLUE + "Hello World")
```

But in the console I got this:

```
>>> [34mHello World
```

I also tried other methods, but none of them help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Python termcolor module](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/):

```
from termcolor import colored
print colored('RED TEXT', 'red'), colored('GREEN TEXT', 'green')
```

You can also look into [sty](https://github.com/feluxe/sty) which is fairly similar to colorama. Here is an example from their GitHub page:

```
foo = fg.red + 'This is red text!' + fg.rs
bar = bg.blue + 'This has a blue background!' + bg.rs
baz = ef.italic + 'This is italic text' + rs.italic
qux = fg(201) + 'This is pink text using 8bit colors' + fg.rs
qui = fg(255, 10, 10) + 'This is red text using 24bit colors.' + fg.rs

# Add new colors:

fg.orange = ('rgb', (255, 150, 50))

buf = fg.orange + 'Yay, Im orange.' + fg.rs

print(foo, bar, baz, qux, qui, buf, sep='\n')
```

[image: Example]

If neither work for you, I would look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors) for more options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the available libraries, but before you can use colored text, you need to run the following code.

```
>>> colorama.init()
```

[image: Terminal screenshot]